# How can I instantiate a class using a 'function handling' style function?

Tags: php, reflection, instantiation

I am trying to implement a Command Pattern style queue and I do not know how to pass arguments to the constructor of the object.

My 'Command' pattern stores the objects in a database, where I have a table `queue_items` storing my 'Command' objects, with the fields `class`, `method`, `constructor_arguments` (stored as an indexed array), `method_arguments` (stored as an indexed array), and `object_type` (which is `enum{'instance','static}`).

If `object_type` is 'instance', I instantiate the object using the 'new' keyword. If `object_type` is 'static', then I just make the call using `forward_static_call_array()`.

If I have no constructor arguments, I can just use something like this:

```
$instance = new $class_name(); //NOTE: no arguments in the constructor
$result = call_user_func_array(array($instance, $method_name), $method_arguments);
```

**But** if I wish to pass the values from the `constructor_arguments` into the `__construct()`, I can not find a function to let me do this.

I wish to keep the indexed array and not to rely on specialised constructors, so that I do not have to rewrite my own and 3rd party classes I use to handle, for example, taking an associative array as the only argument in a constructor.

Does anyone know how to pass an indexed array directly into `__construct` in the fashion of `call_user_func_array()`? Or can it simply not be done?

Drew J. Sonne.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `ReflectionClass` for this special case:

```
$rc = new ReflectionClass($className);
$instance = $rc->newInstanceArgs($array_of_parameters);
```

Answer (score 1):

A more elaborated example using ReflectionClass:

```
<?php
class MyClass
{
    private $arg1;
    private $arg2;

    public function __construct($arg1, $arg2 = "Hello World")
    {
        $this->arg1 = $arg1;
        $this->arg2 = $arg2;
    }

    public function print(){
        echo $this->arg2 . "," .$this->arg2;
    }
}

$class = new ReflectionClass('MyClass');
$args = array(3,"outro");
$instance = $class->newInstanceArgs($args);
$instance->print()

?>
```